# New to CakePHP/Model use

Tags: cakephp

I have a table/model of users, and a certain subset of those users have an entry in a "roles" table.

What is the standard way to create a model that has access to all the users who have one or more entries/rows in the roles table?

Thanks!

Comment: if a user can have more than 1 role, you'll need a hasAndBelongsToMany relationship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to Cake!

One of the coolest and most powerful aspects of Cake is their very [capable ORM](http://api13.cakephp.org/class/model).  Once you figure out Cake's associations and the way they work with databases it's hard to go back to something else.  But, there's a couple things we need to make sure we do with our actual physical database schema before we can do this.

So, let's work with some "sample" data.

```
users
 -------------------------------------------------------
|  id (PK)  |  role_id (FK)  |  username  |  password   |
 -------------------------------------------------------
|     1     |         1      |  cspray     |  ad64675   |
 -------------------------------------------------------
```

...and so on and so on.

```
roles
 --------------------------------------------
|  id (PK)  |              name              |
 --------------------------------------------
|  1        |  Benevolent Dictator for Life  |
 --------------------------------------------
```

...and so on and so on.

Note the name of the tables, `users` and `roles`, and the field names, specifically `id` and `role_id`.  Those are important.  `id` is normally an [auto increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html), `int` field in your database.  There's other ways to store your `id` key but let's not pile too much on at once.

**Now, all this and we haven't answered your question yet!**  Don't worry we're about to get to that.  But, first double check your database schema and make sure those table names and columns are named according to [Cake convention](http://book.cakephp.org/view/903/Model-and-Database-Conventions).  Don't worry I'll wait...

...

Ok!  Now open up your [favorite text editor](http://www.vim.org/) and navigate to `install_dir/app/models/` (where `install_dir` is the name of the folder you have the framework installed in).  Once there create a new file and name it `user.php`.  Inside this file we're gonna use some code that looks like this...

```
class User extends AppModel {

    public $belongsTo = array('Role');

}
```

And, well, there you have it!  You're now free to query the `roles` table from within your `User` class by calling methods through Cake's "association chain", `$this->User->Role->find()`.  You can, and probably should, create a `Role` model just like you created `User`, sans the `$belongsTo`.  Inside it you can define your own methods to interact with the `roles` table and give the information you need to `User`.

I don't want to go too much into how Cake's ORM works though, mostly because if you read through the [Cake Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/) and the [Cake API](http://api13.cakephp.org/) you will find a wealth of knowledge ready to be plucked.

Enjoy your ventures into Cake!

---

So, your model associations are all setup and you're ready to go.  But, where do you go?  Well, you'll want to check out Cake's [Model behaviors](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1071/Behaviors), particularly one of the most important core behaviors, [Containable](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable).  This will allow you to do exactly what you want to do.

Let's just take a look at some code, I'm going to assume that you're already familiar with the [Model::find()](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1017/Retrieving-Your-Data) method.  If not I'd go check that out real quick so you don't get too confused.  It's fairly straight-forward though.

```
class User extends AppModel {

    // provides $this->User->Role
    public $belongsTo = array('Role');

    // gives access to various behaviors
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');

    // custom function
    public function get_users_with_roles() {

        return $this->User->find(
            'contain' => array(
                'Role' => array(     // tells ORM to query `roles` table
                    'Hour',         // <-- tells ORM to query `hours` table
                    'conditions' => array(
                       'Role.id' => '<> NULL'
                    )
                )
            ),
            'fields' => array(
                'User.username'
            )
        );

    }

}
```

This should return all user's usernames (and possibly their `id` and `role_id` as well) that have an entry in the `roles` table.  Note the addition of the new property and the way the "query" is laid out in Cake's ORM.  One thing I could suggest getting comfortable with is multi-dimensional associative arrays, Cake uses a lot of them.

Comment: Ok so I have the associations (they were made naturally from using bake to bake a model). My particular question is if there is a natural way to represent in models just the users who have 1 or more roles, while not selecting for those who have zero roles. I know how to do this in SQL manually, but wanted to know if there was something in the Cake models that I am missing, or if I am thinking about representing it incorrectly. Thanks!

Comment: @p9807 There sure is.  I have to go take care of something right this very moment but give me a few and I will edit my answer that explains more detail about how to work with models.

Comment: thanks for your help. also, one issue on schema convention. Is it more standard in cake to have the foreign keys for something like role as a column in the users? Right now I have the user_id in the role table instead. Just wondering what best practice convention is

Comment: @p9807 This is more a matter of designing your database schema properly then a "do it the Cake way" issue.  For the most part Cake ultimately doesn't care what associations you make, just as long as you use the proper foreign keys.  Based on your question I would have personally designed it the way I described.  But, I don't know your data schema or the rest of your app, those are huge factors.  But, you should take a look at the [`$hasMany`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1043/hasMany) association for that particular schema.

Comment: excellent, thanks so much for the great help, I am already enjoying this new approach. One last question, I am digging through the docs but couldn't find an answer easily...how deep does the recursion go? For each "role", i am defining a hasOne association for "hours". So each role has one hour row associated with it. If I retrieve the "user" data, I see the associated roles, but I would like to also automatically have another level of recursion where each role has the hours associated with it. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: also, should the find include an 'all' as the first element of the array?

Comment: also, seems to return all Users, even those with empty roles. hmm, is there something I am missing about the <> null id constraint?